# AmazonCognito Authentication failing with NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect Username and password

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to authenticate a user and it fails with NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect Username and password.

I did check that the  user is signed up and confirmed and I have no idea what I could be missing.

```
var authenticationData = {
    Username: 'username',
    Password: 'password',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId: 'userpoolid',
    ClientId: 'clientid'
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username: 'username',
    Pool: userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        alert("Success");
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
        console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
    },

    onFailure: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    },

});
```

Comment: Can you clarify which SDK you're using? Are you doing any unique auth flow?

Comment: Username and password are hard-coded. You should send the actual user name and password to Cognito.